# cant recall [HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback] when getting PWM by stm32F746

Tags: timer, pwm, stm32f7

I want to get DutyCycle of PWM use stm32F746G. I did the the code like the hal PWMINPUT sample. Now the program cant go into [HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback] function.

```
#include "main.h"
#define max(a,b) ( ((a)>(b)) ? (a):(b) )
#define min(a,b) ( ((a)>(b)) ? (b):(a) )
#define MASK_R 0xFF
#define MASK_G 0xFF00
#define MASK_B 0xFF0000

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* Timer handler declaration */
TIM_HandleTypeDef    TimHandle;

/* Timer Input Capture Configuration Structure declaration */
TIM_IC_InitTypeDef       sConfig;

/* Slave configuration structure */
TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef   sSlaveConfig;

/* Captured Value */
__IO uint32_t            uwIC2Value = 0;
/* Duty Cycle Value */
__IO uint32_t            uwDutyCycle = 0;
/* Frequency Value */
__IO uint32_t            uwFrequency = 0;

__IO uint32_t   counter1 = 0;

    DMA2D_HandleTypeDef hdma2d_eval;
    /* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
    void SystemClock_Config(void);
     static void LCD_LL_ConvertLineToARGB8888(void *pSrc, void *pDst);
    static void CPU_CACHE_Enable(void);
   int GetRGB(uint32_t color);
  int GetRGBHSI(uint32_t color);
   //static void GPIO_Configuration(void);
   static void Error_Handler(void);



int main(void)
{
uint32_t  i;
uint32_t  *ptrLcd;

/* Enable the CPU Cache */
CPU_CACHE_Enable();

    HAL_Init();

/* Configure the system clock to 216 MHz */
SystemClock_Config();

//GPIO_Configuration();
BSP_LED_Init(LED1);

/*##-1- Initialize the LCD    #################################################*/
BSP_LCD_Init();

/* Init LCD screen buffer */
ptrLcd = (uint32_t*)(LCD_FRAME_BUFFER);
for (i=0; i<(BSP_LCD_GetXSize()*BSP_LCD_GetYSize()); i++)
{
  ptrLcd[i]=0;
}

BSP_LCD_LayerDefaultInit(1, LCD_FRAME_BUFFER);

/* Enable the LCD */
BSP_LCD_DisplayOn();

  /* Select the LCD Foreground layer */
BSP_LCD_SelectLayer(1);

/* Text Introduction Display Begins*/
uint16_t display_duration=0;


BSP_LCD_SetTextColor(LCD_COLOR_ORANGE);
BSP_LCD_SetBackColor(LCD_COLOR_BLACK);

display_duration=0;
while(display_duration<1000)
{
    BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(20, 130, (uint8_t*)"CSIR-CEERI", CENTER_MODE);
    display_duration=display_duration+1;


}

/* Set active window */
BSP_LCD_SetLayerWindow(1, xoffset, yoffset, xsize, ysize);
//HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&htim1,TIM_CHANNEL_2);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOI,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* Set TIMx instance */
  TimHandle.Instance = TIMx;
  TimHandle.Init.Period            = 0xFFFF;
  TimHandle.Init.Prescaler         = 0;
  TimHandle.Init.ClockDivision     = 0;
  TimHandle.Init.CounterMode       = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  TimHandle.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  //TimHandle.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&TimHandle) != HAL_OK)
    {
      /* Initialization Error */
      Error_Handler();
    }
/* Common configuration */
  sConfig.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
  sConfig.ICFilter = 0;

/* Configure the Input Capture of channel 1 */
  sConfig.ICPolarity = TIM_ICPOLARITY_FALLING;
  sConfig.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_INDIRECTTI;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&TimHandle, &sConfig, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
      /* Configuration Error */
      Error_Handler();
    }
/* Configure the Input Capture of channel 2 */
  sConfig.ICPolarity = TIM_ICPOLARITY_RISING;
  sConfig.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&TimHandle, &sConfig, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
   {
     /* Configuration Error */
     Error_Handler();
   }
/*##-3- Configure the slave mode ###########################################*/
/* Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode  */
  sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode        = TIM_SLAVEMODE_RESET;
  sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger     = TIM_TS_TI2FP2;
  sSlaveConfig.TriggerPolarity  = TIM_TRIGGERPOLARITY_NONINVERTED;
  sSlaveConfig.TriggerPrescaler = TIM_TRIGGERPRESCALER_DIV1;
  sSlaveConfig.TriggerFilter    = 0;
  if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&TimHandle, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
      /* Configuration Error */
      Error_Handler();
    }
  /*##-4- Start the Input Capture in interrupt mode ##########################*/
   if (HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&TimHandle, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
   {
     /* Starting Error */
     Error_Handler();
   }
   //BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(20, 20, (uint8_t*)"OK1", LEFT_MODE);
   /*##-5- Start the Input Capture in interrupt mode ##########################*/
   if (HAL_TIM_IC_Start(&TimHandle, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
   {
     /* Starting Error */
     Error_Handler();
   }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
while(1)
{


}

 }

 static void Error_Handler(void)
 {
  /* Turn LED3 on */
  BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(0, 180, (uint8_t*)"fl!", LEFT_MODE);
  while (1)
  {
 }
}
```

/**
  * @brief  Input Capture callback in non blocking mode
  * @param  htim : TIM IC handle
  * @retval None
  */

```
void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(20, 20, (uint8_t*)"OK!", RIGHT_MODE);
 if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2)
 {
   /* Get the Input Capture value */
  uwIC2Value = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

if (uwIC2Value != 0)
{
  /* Duty cycle computation */
    //uwDutyCycle = ((HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_1)) * 100) / uwIC2Value;
    uwDutyCycle = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  /* uwFrequency computation
  TIM3 counter clock = (RCC_Clocks.HCLK_Frequency) */
  uwFrequency = (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/ 2)  / uwIC2Value;
    char s;
    itoa(uwIC2Value,s,10);
    BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(0, 200, (uint8_t*)s, LEFT_MODE);

    char f;
    itoa(uwDutyCycle,f,10);
    BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(0, 272-Font24.Height, (uint8_t*)f, LEFT_MODE);
  //TIM_RESET_CAPTUREPOLARITY(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  //TIM_RESET_CAPTUREPOLARITY(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_2);


}
else
{
  uwDutyCycle = 0;
  uwFrequency = 0;
}
```

}
}

Answer (score -1):

finish it.

void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

```
if (htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2)
{
/* Get the Input Capture value */
uwIC2Value = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

if (uwIC2Value != 0)
{
    /* Duty cycle computation */
    uwIC1Value = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    uwIC2Value = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
    //per_HL = (uwIC2Value* 100000)/(uwIC1Value-uwIC2Value)+1;
    per_HL = (uwIC2Value* 100000)/(uwIC1Value)+1;
    /* uwTemp computation
    TIM3 counter clock = (RCC_Clocks.HCLK_Frequency) */
    uwTemp = 421-(751*per_HL/100000);

    Temp  = (int)((uwTemp+4)*1000);


    itoa(Temp,c_Temp,10);
    BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(0, 220, "CO:(PPB)", RIGHT_MODE);
    BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(0, 190, (uint8_t*)c_Temp, RIGHT_MODE);

    __HAL_TIM_SetCounter(htim,0);
}
else
{
  uwDutyCycle = 0;
  uwFrequency = 0;
}
```

}
}

Comment: Finish what? Can you provide more context about your answer and mark the parts that are most important? A later visitor should learn from it, learn the algorithm you use and not just copy and paste it